Recurrent relationship between determinants of matrix sequence?
Consider a set of matrices $A_n$ of size $2n \times 2n$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, made of $2\times 4$ rectangular blocks in the following way:
$$A_2 = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11}& a_{12} & 0 & 0 \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
0 & 0 & a_{43} & a_{44} \end{bmatrix}$$
$$A_3 = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11}& a_{12} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & 0 & 0 \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} &0&0 \\
0 & 0 & a_{43} & a_{44} &  a_{45}& a_{46} \\
0 & 0 & a_{53} & a_{54} &  a_{55}& a_{56} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  a_{65}& a_{66} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$A_4 = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11}& a_{12} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} &0&0& 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_{43} & a_{44} &  a_{45}& a_{46}& 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_{53} & a_{54} &  a_{55}& a_{56} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  a_{65}& a_{66} & a_{67}& a_{68}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  a_{75}& a_{76} & a_{77}& a_{78}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0&0 & a_{87}& a_{88}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$A_5 = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11}& a_{12} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 0 \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 0\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} &0&0& 0 & 0& 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_{43} & a_{44} &  a_{45}& a_{46}& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & a_{53} & a_{54} &  a_{55}& a_{56} & 0 & 0& 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  a_{65}& a_{66} & a_{67}& a_{68}& 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  a_{75}& a_{76} & a_{77}& a_{78}& 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0&0 & a_{87}& a_{88}& a_{89} & a_{8,10}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0&0 & a_{97}& a_{98}& a_{99} & a_{9,10}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0&0 & 0 & 0 & a_{10,9}& a_{10,10}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
I am looking for the relationship between $\det(A_n)$ and $\det(A_{n+1})$. Using Mathematica, I can see what appears to be a non-trivial but seemingly recursive relationship. It involves a lot of differences of the form $a_{46}a_{53}-a_{43}a_{56}$ and I can imagine they can be proven using the cofactor calculation of determinants. But I can't finish the computations because the cofactors strike out a line and a column of $A_{n}$ which "breaks" the determinants of the submatrix $A_{n-1}$.
My final goal is to speed up the computation of the roots of the determinants by reusing the results for previous smaller $n$. Any clue appreciated.

Here's a possible approach. Partition the matrix as follows:
$$
A_{n} = \begin{bmatrix}
A_{n-1} & B_n\\
C_n & D_n
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
For instance,
$$
A_4 = \left[\begin{array}{rrrrrr|rr} a_{11}& a_{12} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} &0&0& 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_{43} & a_{44} &  a_{45}& a_{46}& 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_{53} & a_{54} &  a_{55}& a_{56} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  a_{65}& a_{66} & a_{67}& a_{68}\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  a_{75}& a_{76} & a_{77}& a_{78}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0&0 & a_{87}& a_{88}\\ 
\end{array}\right]
$$
From there, you can use the block-matrix determinant
$$
\det(A_n) = \det(D_{n})\det(A_{n-1} - B_nD_n^{-1}C_n).
$$
$D_n$ is $2 \times 2$ and therefore easy to invert. We can further rewrite this using Sylvester's determinant theorem, noting that
$$
\det(A_{n-1} - B_nD_n^{-1}C_n) = \\
\det(A_{n-1})\det(I - A_{n-1}^{-1}B_nD_n^{-1}C_n) = \\
\det(A_{n-1})\det(I - D_n^{-1}C_nA_{n-1}^{-1}B_n)
$$
Note that we can get this result by computing $A_{n-1}^{-1}B_n$, which only requires calculating the final column of $A_{n-1}^{-1}$.
